# What process (nm) are Microchip SAM D 21 microcontrollers made on?

Tags: microchip, process

I'm assuming that the whole family is made on the same process, but specifically I'm looking for ATSAMD21G18A series.

Comment: Half out of thin air but probably 90nm.

Comment: Had also assumed 90nm, but it looks like they don't officially say what node is used.